# I am building a product review app in my Django eCommerce project. I can't get my review form to display on a template from the main shop app

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Here is my set up:

using Django 3.2.21.
bootstrap4

review/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from shop.models import Product


class Reviews(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='review')
    body = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='review')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Review {self.rating} {self.body} by {self.author}"
```

reviews/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from shop.models import Product
from .models import Reviews
from .forms import ReviewForm


def review(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        review_form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        print(review_form)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            print(review_form)
            review_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully reviewed product')
            return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[product.id]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed to add product. \
                Please check the form data is correct')
    else:
        review_form = ReviewForm()
        print(review_form)

    template = 'shop/product_detail.html'
    context = {
        'review_form': review_form,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

reviews/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('review/<int:product_id>/', views.review, name='review'),
]
```

reviews/forms.py

```
from .models import Reviews
from django import forms


class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = (
            'body',
            'rating',
            )
```

shop/product_detail.html  (Where I have two forms the first one is working, but the review_form not rendering fields)

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags % }


{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 offset-lg-2">
            <div class="image-container my-5">
                {% if product.image %}
                <a href="{{ product.image.url }}" target="_blank">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="product-details-container mb-5 mt-md-5 text-left">
                <p class="mb-2">Album Title: <strong>{{ product.name }}</strong></p>
                {% if product.artist %}
                <p class="mb-2">Artist: <strong>{{ product.artist }}</strong></p>
                {% else %}
                <p class="mb-0"></p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if product.release_date %}
                <p class="mb-2">Year Released: <strong>{{ product.release_date }}</strong></p>
                {% else %}
                <p class="mb-0"></p>
                {% endif %}
                <p class="mb-2">{{ product.description }}</p>
                <p class="lead mb-0 font-weight-bold">€{{ product.price }}</p>
                {% if product.category %}
                <p class="small mt-1 mb-0 tags">
                    <a class="mx-3" href="{% url 'shop' %}?category={{ product.category.name }}">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-hashtag"></i>{{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                    </a>
                    <a class="mx-3" href="{% url 'shop' %}?genre={{ product.genre.name }}">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-hashtag"></i>{{ product.genre.friendly_name }}
                    </a>
                </p>
                {% endif %}

                <form class="form" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' product.id %}?source=product_detail" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row">

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p class="mt-3"><strong>Quantity:</strong></p>
                            <div class="form-group w-50">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <button class="decrement-qty btn btn-dark rounded-0"
                                            data-item_id="{{ product.id }}" id="decrement-qty_{{ product.id }}">
                                            <span>
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="form-control qty_input text-center" type="number" name="quantity"
                                        value="1" min="1" max="99" data-item_id="{{ product.id }}"
                                        id="id_qty_{{ product.id }}">

                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="increment-qty btn btn-dark rounded-0"
                                            data-item_id="{{ product.id }}" id="decrement-qty_{{ product.id }}">
                                            <span>
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <a href="{% url 'shop' %}" class="btn btn-outline-black rounded-0 mt-5">
                                <span class="icon">
                                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text-uppercase">Keep Shopping</span>
                            </a>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-black rounded-0 text-uppercase mt-5"
                                value="Add to Cart">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="{{ request.path }}">
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3>Reviews</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3>Leave a Review</h3>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'review' product.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ review_form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit review">
            </form>
               
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block postloadjs %}
{{ block.super }}
{% include 'shop/includes/quantity_input_script.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Edit: I have added the other form from the product template(add_to_cart) and the reviews/forms.py , also there was a typo in the reviews/views.py, referencing the ProductForm instead of the ReviewForm, From when I was trying something different, I have changed it back to ReviewForm and the issue still continues. I have two forms on the same page, one is adding a quantity of a product and adding it to the cart and the other one I am trying to render is a review form for customers to leave a review on that specific product. If anyone needs anymore info let me know, thanks for having a look

The model and form file to me look ok they are also set up in the revies app. The main project level urls.py path looks ok. I have other apps in the project all set up ok. On the product_detail template there is another form for adding item to cart which is working.

I have tried changing around urls and rewriting the view differently but nothing working.
The title and submit button are displaying with no fields. but when clicking the sumbit button it is calling the other form on the page with a (Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found) error, add_to_cart_is the other forms view within the shop app.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong I am only learning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the `ProductForm`, `ReviewForm`.

Comment: Also, you say on the **product_detail.html**, does that mean you have two forms on the same page? Can you show them both?